# Optimizing nested loop for calculating geodesic distance

Tags: performance, graph, matlab

I segmented an image into N superpixels and constructed a graph based on that in which each superpixel is considered as a node. The information about neighbor superpixels is stored in `glcms` array. The weight between each pair of neighboring superpixels is stored in matrix `W`.

Finally, I want to compute [geodesic distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/728061) between non-adjacent superpixels using `graphshortestpath` function. The following code does the mentioned process, however it is very time-consuming. Specifically, the last section of the code that computes geodesic distance takes more time than expected (more than 15 sec).

```matlab
    Img=imread('input.jpg');
    [rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(Img);
    [L,N] = superpixels(Img,250);

    %Identifying neighborhood relationships
    glcms = graycomatrix(L,'NumLevels',N,'GrayLimits',[1,N],'Offset',  [0,1;1,0]); %Create gray-level co-occurrence matrix from image
    glcms = sum(glcms,3);    % add together the two matrices
    glcms = glcms + glcms.'; % add upper and lower triangles together, make it symmetric
    glcms(1:N+1:end) = 0;    % set the diagonal to zero, we don't want to see "1 is neighbor of 1"

    data = zeros(N,3);
    for labelVal = 1:N
    redIdx = idx{labelVal};
    greenIdx = idx{labelVal}+numRows*numCols;
    blueIdx = idx{labelVal}+2*numRows*numCols;
    data(labelVal,1) = mean(Img(redIdx));
    data(labelVal,2) = mean(Img(greenIdx));
    data(labelVal,3) = mean(Img(blueIdx));

    end    

   Euc=zeros(N);
% Euclidean Distance
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if glcms(i,j)~=0
            Euc(i,j)=sqrt(((data(i,1)-data(j,1))^2)+((data(i,2)-data(j,2))^2)+((data(i,3)-data(j,3))^2));
        end
    end
end


W=zeros(N);
W_num=zeros(N);

W_den=zeros(N);
OMG1=0.1;
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if(Euc(i,j)~=0)
         W_num(i,j)=exp(-OMG1*(Euc(i,j)));
         W_den(i,i)=W_num(i,j)+W_den(i,i);
        end
    end
end

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
         if(Euc(i,j)~=0)
             W(i,j)=(W_num(i,j))/(W_den(i,i));   % Connectivity Matrix W

         end
    end
end


s_star_temp=zeros(N);   %temporary variable for geodesic distance measurement
W_sparse=zeros(N);
W_sparse=sparse(W);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if W(i,j)==0 & i~=j;
            s_star_temp(i,j)=graphshortestpath(W_sparse,i,j); % Geodesic Distance
        end
    end
end
```

The question is how to optimize the code to be more efficient , i.e. less time-consuming.

Comment: Please [format the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960822/how-can-i-reformat-code-in-matlab-editor/37362250) to make its structure clear to your potential reviewers. Having well-formatted and consistently indented code will help the reviewers concentrate on the more interesting topics.

Answer (score 3):

I'll first go through the different section and outline possible improvements, then give some general comments at the end. I am not checking the algorithm for correctness, as I don't know it.

```
Img=imread('input.jpg');
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(Img);
[L,N] = superpixels(Img,250);

%Identifying neighborhood relationships
glcms = graycomatrix(L,'NumLevels',N,'GrayLimits',[1,N],'Offset',  [0,1;1,0]); %Create gray-level co-occurrence matrix from image
glcms = sum(glcms,3);    % add together the two matrices
glcms = glcms + glcms.'; % add upper and lower triangles together, make it symmetric
glcms(1:N+1:end) = 0;    % set the diagonal to zero, we don't want to see "1 is neighbor of 1"
```

You need to have defined `idx` by now, but you haven't, so the code doesn't run. Based on the `superpixels` documentation, you need to add `idx = label2idx(L);`

```
data = zeros(N,3);
for labelVal = 1:N
    redIdx = idx{labelVal};
    greenIdx = idx{labelVal}+numRows*numCols;
    blueIdx = idx{labelVal}+2*numRows*numCols;
    data(labelVal,1) = mean(Img(redIdx));
    data(labelVal,2) = mean(Img(greenIdx));
    data(labelVal,3) = mean(Img(blueIdx));
end
```

This is fine, it probably is fine to just write `data(labelVal,1) = mean(Img(idx{1:N}))`, etc. but the performance should be similar.

```
Euc = zeros(N);
% Euclidean Distance
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if glcms(i,j)~=0
            Euc(i,j)=sqrt(((data(i,1)-data(j,1))^2)+((data(i,2)-data(j,2))^2)+((data(i,3)-data(j,3))^2));
        end
    end
end
```

This can be replaced by `Euc = pdist2(data,data).*(glcms~=0);`

```
W=zeros(N);
W_num=zeros(N);

W_den=zeros(N);
OMG1=0.1;
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if(Euc(i,j)~=0)
         W_num(i,j)=exp(-OMG1*(Euc(i,j)));
         W_den(i,i)=W_num(i,j)+W_den(i,i);
        end
    end
end
```

This can be replaced by `W_num = exp(-OMG1*Euc).*(Euc~=0);` and `W_den = sum(W_num);` (here `W_den` is a vector, not a matrix, but that's what you want because you were only using diagonal elements of your `W_den` matrix).

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
         if(Euc(i,j)~=0)
             W(i,j)=(W_num(i,j))/(W_den(i,i));   % Connectivity Matrix W
         end
    end
end
```

This can be replace by `W = W_num./W_den.';` and `W(isnan(W)) = 0;`.

```
s_star_temp=zeros(N);   %temporary variable for geodesic distance measurement
W_sparse=zeros(N);
W_sparse=sparse(W);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if W(i,j)==0 & i~=j;
            s_star_temp(i,j)=graphshortestpath(W_sparse,i,j); % Geodesic Distance
        end
    end
end
```

Here you define `W_sparse` twice, you don't need to initialise it with `zeros(N)`. This part is finding all shortest paths, and there is a builtin for that (which is probably a lot more efficient that generating the paths independently). Replace this whole section with `s_star_temp = graphallshortestpaths(W).*(W==0);` This seems to speed it up from ~15 seconds to 0.005 seconds.

---

So this is how I would write your algorithm

```
Img = imread('input.jpg');
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(Img);
[L,N] = superpixels(Img,250);

idx = label2idx(L);

%Identifying neighborhood relationships
glcms = graycomatrix(L,'NumLevels',N,'GrayLimits',[1,N],'Offset',  [0,1;1,0]); %Create gray-level co-occurrence matrix from image
glcms = sum(glcms,3);    % add together the two matrices
glcms = glcms + glcms.'; % add upper and lower triangles together, make it symmetric
glcms(1:N+1:end) = 0;    % set the diagonal to zero, we don't want to see "1 is neighbor of 1"

data = zeros(N,3);
for labelVal = 1:N
    data(labelVal,1) = mean(Img(idx{labelVal}));
    data(labelVal,2) = mean(Img(idx{labelVal}+rows*columns));
    data(labelVal,3) = mean(Img(idx{labelVal}+2*rows*columns));
end

Euc = sparse(pdist2(data,data).*(glcms~=0));

OMG1 = 0.1;

W_num = exp(-OMG1*Euc).*(Euc~=0);
W_den = sum(W_num);

W = W_num./W_den.';
W(isnan(W)) = 0;

s_star_temp = graphallshortestpaths(W).*(W==0);
```

Notice that I made `Euc` a sparse matrix. This makes the resulting matrices (`W_num`, `W_den`, `W`) also sparse. Your original code left them as full matrices, which was unnecessary. This code runs in about 1.3 seconds on my machine, compared to about 16 for your original code (with the picture I used).

---

Minor general comments on your code:

- Use spaces around your `=` signs, it makes things easier to read
- Try to avoid very long lines, for example the `graycomatrix` line with its comment will go over the end of the window and be lost
- Write more comments
- Matlab best practice is to avoid using `i` and `j` for loop variables, prefer `ii` and `jj`. It's not very important, but `i` and `j` can also mean the imaginary unit.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `Euc` is symmetric so it doesn't matter, but it does let you do `W = W_num./W_den;` on the next line.

Comment: You're absolutely right, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

Just a few tips and tricks to add to [David's excellent answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237402/151754).

---

---

```matlab
data = zeros(N,3);
for labelVal = 1:N
    redIdx = idx{labelVal};
    greenIdx = idx{labelVal}+numRows*numCols;
    blueIdx = idx{labelVal}+2*numRows*numCols;
    data(labelVal,1) = mean(Img(redIdx));
    data(labelVal,2) = mean(Img(greenIdx));
    data(labelVal,3) = mean(Img(blueIdx));
end
```

Here, `idx` is linear indices into the first channel of `Img`. `Img` is a 3D array, with channels along the 3rd dimension. The indexing `Img(redIdx)`, `Img(greenIdx)` and `Img(blueIdx)` simply index into `idx`, `idx+number_of_pixels` and `idx+2*number_of_pixels`. Instead, we can transform `Img` into a 2D array, where all pixels are along one dimension and channels along the other. Now `idx` indexes the first dimension, and `Img(idx,:)` are the pixels given by `idx`. The code above simplifies to:

```matlab
data = zeros(N,3);
Img = reshape(Img,[],3); % note that this is essentially free, no data is copied.
for labelVal = 1:N
    data(labelVal,:) = mean(Img(idx{labelVal},:),1); % compute mean along 1st dimension
end
```

(Don't overwrite `Img` if you need it later, you can use a temporary variable instead, in either case there won't be any data copied.)

---

---

```matlab
W_den=zeros(N);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if(Euc(i,j)~=0)
            %...
            W_den(i,i)=W_num(i,j)+W_den(i,i);
        end
    end
end
```

Here you only use the diagonal elements of `W_den`, the other `N*(N-1)` elements are never used. Instead, define `W_den` as a vector:

```matlab
W_den = zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if(Euc(i,j)~=0)
            %...
            W_den(i) = W_num(i,j) + W_den(i);
        end
    end
end
```

This saves a lot of memory, and also speeds up computation because of the reduced cache pressure.

Written this way, it is trival to see that we can rewrite:

```matlab
W_den = zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
    W_den(i) = sum(W_num(i,Euc(i,:)~=0));
end
```

But David already showed how to simplify this bit of code even further by using the knowledge that `W_num` is zero where `Euc` is zero. In this case, `W_den = sum(W_num,2)`.

---

---

```matlab
Euc=zeros(N);
% Euclidean Distance
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if glcms(i,j)~=0
            Euc(i,j)=sqrt(((data(i,1)-data(j,1))^2)+((data(i,2)-data(j,2))^2)+((data(i,3)-data(j,3))^2));
        end
    end
end
```

David suggested using `pdist`, but we can also do this manually, which I show here to illustrate how to compute with matrices in MATLAB avoiding loops. I'll simplify the code step by step. First the expression within the inner loop can be simplified using vector operations:

```matlab
Euc=zeros(N);
% Euclidean Distance
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if glcms(i,j)~=0
            Euc(i,j)=sqrt(sum((data(i,:)-data(j,:)).^2));
        end
    end
end
```

Next we remove the `if` statement:

```matlab
Euc=zeros(N);
% Euclidean Distance
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        Euc(i,j) = (glcms(i,j)~=0) * sqrt(sum((data(i,:)-data(j,:)).^2));
    end
end
```

Multiplying by the logical value `glcms(i,j)~=0` will set any elements where `glcms` is zero to 0. Next we remove the inner loop:

```matlab
Euc=zeros(N);
% Euclidean Distance
for i=1:N
    Euc(i,:) = (glcms(i,:)~=0) .* sqrt(sum((data(i,:)-data).^2,2));
end
```

Here we explicitly sum over the 2nd dimension, by default MATLAB sums over the first non-singleton dimension (dimension with more than one element). It is good practice to always explicitly state which dimension to sum over.

Finally, removing the outer loop is more complicated because it requires reshaping arrays:

```matlab
% Euclidean Distance
Euc = (glcms~=0) .* sqrt(sum((reshape(data,[],1,3)-reshape(data,1,[],3)).^2,3));
```

We've reshaped `data` in two different ways, to a `N`x1x3 array and to a 1x`N`x3 array. Subtracting these two arrays leads to a `N`x`N`x3 array. We take the square of the array, then sum along the new 3rd dimension (which corresponds to the original 2nd dimension).